# Initializing Membership Provider by code

Tags: c#, web-config, membership-provider

I am trying to Initialize SQL Membership Provider by code and everything is working fine in the **first** request only!. ***When the code below executes again (after refreshing the page for example) I get the following error***:

> The attribute 'connectionStringName' is missing or empty.

**Page Load Code:**

```
MembershipSection membershipSection = (MembershipSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/membership");
                    string sqlProviderName = "AspNetSqlMembershipProvider";
                    NameValueCollection providerConfig;
                    providerConfig = membershipSection.Providers[sqlProviderName].Parameters; // returning empty list in the second request
                    var _SqlProvider = new SqlMembershipProvider();
                    _SqlProvider.Initialize(sqlProviderName, providerConfig);
```

**Web.config:**

```
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
      <providers>  
        <clear />  
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Encrypted" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" passwordAttemptWindow="10" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Any Advice?

Comment: Microsoft answer !! https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/813107/membership-provider-parameters-disappear-after-first-request

Answer (score 0):

how about just keep your data/connectionstring/obj at static level (as like singleton)?

it's not like connectionstring is going to be change throughout the web instance, does it?

```
static string/dataType _DataToBeRead1timeOnly = null;
static string/dataType DataToBeRead1timeOnly 
{
  get {
    if (_DataToBeRead1timeOnly == null) { _DataToBeRead1timeOnly = .... }
    return _DataToBeRead1timeOnly;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but this is a workaround , I can cache anything but I believe that web.config configuration is already cached.